# Adding slug to my table in corrospondance to the field's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[my groups table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JDaS.png)

i have a table named groups and and the name of the group is present there, how do i change it to slug (seperate names by "-") and save the created slug in a column

I dont have to use any gem in this i have searched about .parameterized function tho

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the slug to look like? What attributes to include? What do to when two records would lead to the same slug?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem or do it youserlf (not recommended) with a before_save callback on your model.

Let say you have a name column, create a slug column in a migration.
Then in your model:

```
before_save :slugify

private
def slugify
  self.slug = name.strip.gsub(' ', '-')
end
```

This is just an example, you will need far more customization for a proper working slug system (no duplicates, etc).

My advice : use the gem.